# Best way to create a UI table in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, grid, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to design a table UI for my activity. I would like three columns and a fixed number of rows (so that the view fill all allotted space). Each of the cells should be clickable, and able to host standard widgets such as textview of buttons. I also want to control the scrolling (virtual grid with infinite up/down data). Pretty much something like the image below.

[image: grid with fixed number of rows]

What is the recommended way of making a UI like this?

1. ListView?
2. TableLayout with dynamically added rows?
3. Custom class derived from View?
4. OpenGL?

I tried both 1 & 2, but so far have not been happy (hard to control height of each row). Any comments and code samples welcome.

Comment: Refer below link which will help you: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/

Comment: Looks interesting. I did something like this in the past. My question is - how can you determine the number of rows to put into your adapter so that the grid takes the whole screen?

Comment: @Filip Android devices comes in a variety of resolutions, so you can't assume anything regarding the size/height of the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Your app looks like it works with DB. If so `TableLayout` is not good to work with things like [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)/ [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)/ [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)…

Custom view is up to you but I think, based on the image, `ListView` is good enough. And let it manage the row height itself, that's not a big deal.

I'm not sure about OpenGL. For simple thing, I'd choose `ListView`/ `GridView`.